# What does "None for c in" stand for?

Tags: python, dictionary, ord

I am looking an example code, it said:

```
subj = 'A.B!c?'
dd = {ord(c):None for c in 'chars_to_remove'}
subj.translate(dd)
```

The output is **'A.B!?'** . 
It seems to me ord(c): is a "dictionary", if every element in the string(subj) meets c then c will be removed.

But I cannot get full picture of this statement, I don't understand:

1. Is c means every element of string?
2. What does "None for c" means?
3. If I simply replace "chars_to_remove" to "k", then output will become **'A.B!c?'**, why?

Please help clear my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading it in the wrong way

```
{ord(c):None for c in 'chars_to_remove'}
```

is `ord(c):None` and `for c in 'chars_to_remove'`

`for c in 'chars_to_remove'` goes through every char in this string 'chars_to_remove'

`ord(c):None` when added to the dictionary and used in `translate()`, it replaces those char to None

The only char in this String that is in your subj is 'c', so therefore your subj becomes 'A.B!?'

Comment: I kind of confuse, there are two sting, one is 'A.B!c?' another one is 'chars_to_remove'. If the main purpose is to remove c from 'A.B!c?', why should have for c in 'chars_to_remove' statement.

Comment: I think I understand the meaning:
`subj = 'A.B!C?'
dd = {ord(input):None for input in 'ABC'}
subj.translate(dd) `
the output is **.!?***, so for input in 'xxx', xxx means all character you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

You should read it as `ord(c): None` pause `for c in 'chars_to_remove`.

What happens is that you insert `ord(c): None` in your dict, for every character `c` of your string `'chars_to_remove'`.